# Sorting Families on Plp

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, category-listing, product-listing, customization

First product list A1, A2,A3
Product Family A
Second product list B1,B2,B3
Product Family B

It shows on PLP such as in this way;

Family A Title
Family A description
A1 A2 A3

Family B Title
Family B description
B1 B2 B3

How can I change the order of Families?
Ex. I would like to show family B on the top. However magento is sorting as in alphabetical order.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your code ? Depends of your implementation but you can add a position field to sort your families.

Another solution is to use category (not visible in menu) to manage families and just link product to categories.

for example:

- Root Families Category

  - Family 1

    - P1
    - P2
  - Family 2

    - P1
      [...]